# Access denied for 'root@localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: php, mysql, macos, laravel, mamp

I recently installed mac OSX. I installed latest version of mamp.

I was trying to setup my database, but i got this error.

> Access denied for 'root@localhost' (using password: NO)

my `.env` file --

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=some
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

My MySQL port is 3306, Apache port is 80 (I changed it).

I don't change the password of PhpMyAdmin. But I get an error like this.

So I tried entering some password, then it is giving me same error with password using: YES

How can I fix it?

Comment: try changing 127.0.0.1 to localhost

Comment: Are you using the correct password in .env?

Comment: By Default mamp PHP myadmin password is ROOT. So did you tried with root as password ?

Comment: You are try to enter Wrong password.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using MAMP try this.

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=some
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

Open your MAMP
There your will see 3 options 
1. Preferences
2. Open WebStart Page
3. Start / Stop Servers

**Click second one [ Open WebStart Page]**. It will open mamp info page. Under MySQL area you can see your database connection details.

[image: MAMP Start]

[image: See your connection details]

Hope it will help you.